# Multi raw input bash automation

Tags: python, bash, server

I have a python script and it has many rawinput.
I must write a bash script to put it in a loop but how can I insert the answer of raw input
normally I can do it with pipe "|" if it has only one raw input.

how can I insert the answers of multi rawinputs?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `rawinput` reads exactly one line. Just supply more than one line.

```
{ echo "first line"; echo "second line"; } | python yourscript.py
```

or

```
python yourscript.py <<EOF
first line
second line
EOF
```